# Does it make sense to have a primary key attribute in Core Data in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsmanagedobjectmodel

In `iOS 9`, I can specify certain attributes in an entity to be `unique constraints` to prevent managed objects with the same unique constraints to be created.

Each `NSManagedObject` has its own `ObjectId` but maintained internally by `Core Data` and cannot be set as unique constraint in the model.

Based on that notion, does it make sense to include a "`primary key`" attribute for all entities in core data and specify the primary key as unique constraint if I don't want duplicate data?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a meaningful way to source and populate that key, and the elimination of duplicates means something to you, then yes.

If you don't have a source of a meaningful value for the key, like a server generated value, then all you're doing is adding a requirement that you need to find the key first, and you'd be doing that anyway to avoid duplication. So adding it without 'external' support generally won't help.